# How to save clipped object to stl with python vtk

Tags: python, vtk

I was following [clipDataSetWithPolyData](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Meshes/ClipDataSetWithPolyData/)

I want to save the clipped square into stl file.

[image: Clipped image]

It seems that if I use the stl writer to write it out

```
clipperOutsideMapper = vtkDataSetMapper()
clipperOutsideMapper.SetInputConnection(clipper.GetOutputPort(1))
clipperOutsideMapper.ScalarVisibilityOff()
# use stl writer to write clipped cube into stl file
stlWriter = vtkSTLWriter()
stlWriter.SetFileName("clippedSqure.stl")
stlWriter.SetInputConnection(clipper.GetOutputPort(1))
stlWriter.Write()
```

It always throws this error. I mean it can render the clipped cube in the rendered window but why it cannot be saved?

```
2023-01-29 17:43:08.985 (   5.569s) [          22AD7D]vtkDemandDrivenPipeline:760    ERR| vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0x7fad6c4bb220): Input for connection index 0 on input port index 0 for algorithm vtkSTLWriter(0x7fad6c4bac80) is of type vtkUnstructuredGrid, but a vtkPolyData is required.
2023-01-29 17:43:08.985 (   5.569s) [          22AD7D]vtkDemandDrivenPipeline:760    ERR| vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0x7fad6c4bb220): Input for connection index 0 on input port index 0 for algorithm vtkSTLWriter(0x7fad6c4bac80) is of type vtkUnstructuredGrid, but a vtkPolyData is required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out myself. The issue was stl writer was asking for a `vtkPolyData`, however only `vtkUnstructuredGrid` was provided. Thus, we need to transfer from `vtkUnstructuredGrid` to `vtkPolyData` by using the following code wrote by myself.

```
stlFilter = vtkDataSetSurfaceFilter()
stlFilter.SetInputConnection(clipper.GetOutputPort(1))
stlFilter.Update()
```

Then you just write `stl` file now:

```
stlWriter = vtkSTLWriter()
stlWriter.SetFileName("clippedSqure.stl")
stlWriter.SetInputConnection(stlFilter.GetOutputPort())
stlWriter.Write()
```

Hope it helps everybody who has similar problems.